# How to insert an number value to a oracle db

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, numbers

i have a problem with my code. My code is working fine, but i want to insert a decimal number in my oracle table (the type of the field in oracle is number).

"Gewicht" is a textfield where the user have to type a decimal number in. actually i can insert just full numbers but i cant insert decimal.

my oracle datafields:
TOUR - VARCHAR2 (20 BYTE)
GEWICHT - NUMBER

I have no much experience about programming so i give my best. Its my first Script :).

```
 private void insert()
    {
        try
        {


            String connectionString = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = " +
          "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = IP-Adress)(PORT = 1521))" +
          "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
          " (SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
          " (SERVICE_NAME = NAME)" +
          ")" +
          ");User Id = USER;password=password;";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            con.Open();

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into TABLENAME (TOUR,GEWICHT) values ('" + this.comboBox1.Text + "'," + Gewicht.Text+ ")";



            cmd.Connection = con;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Erfolgreich eingefügt");
            comboBox1.Text = String.Empty;
            Gewicht.Clear();
            viewdata();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fehler");
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you currently execute your code?

Comment: When i execute the actually code, it inserts a full number.

Comment: Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the tags and add the definition of your table - all the field names and data types. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes in your insert query string. In any case, use parameters like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into TABLENAME (TOUR,GEWICHT) values (@tour,@wicht)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@tour", OracleDbType.NVarChar2).Value = this.comboBox1.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@wicht", OracleDbType.Decimal).Value = Decimal.Parse(Gewicht.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. How can i insert a decimal number in this case?

Comment: :( its actually dont working with this code.
 "System.ArgumentException" in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Comment: What are the datatypes of TOUR and GEWICHT in your Database?

Comment: TOUR is VARCHAR2 and GEWICHT is NUMBER
i tried to make GEWICHT to VARCHAR too but it didnt worked.

Comment: Actually the same issue. 
 "System.ArgumentException" in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll

Thank you very much for your help